# Manually fail #update_attributes save in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, error-handling

I'm calling `@foo.update` and inside 1 of the attributes it's updating, I'm calling a the write method (`def attribute=`) in `foo`'s model class and want it to fail the entire update conditionally. What can I put in there? I tried using `errors[:base]` but it doesn't fail the `save`. I can't use `validates` either because the attribute will be transformed into something else before it gets saved.

```
  def attribute=(attr)
    if bar
      # code to fail entire db save
    end
  end
```

Comment: how did you try to use errors[:base]?

Comment: Is raising an error and catching outside the save an option?

Comment: @ruby_newbie I placed it inside the `if bar` conditional above with `errors[:base] << "failed"`

Comment: It does not seem to be the right place. If your condition needs values from other fields, the other fields may have not been assigned yet. If this validation is really that special, then you can have a validate method in the model and call it from controller after `SomeModel.new(params)` and before `save`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check the condition on a `before_save` callback in model `foo.rb` and return false if you don't want to save it.

```
before_save :really_want_to_save?

private

def really_want_to_save?
  conditional_says_yes ? true : false
end
```

If you want error message too, then

```
def really_want_to_save?
  if conditional_says_yes
    true
  else
    errors[:base] << "failed"
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: what's the difference between using a `before_save` vs. validate? does one come before another? does the `before_save` come before the setter method?

Comment: `before_save` runs before `validations` and the idea behind it is if you want to manipulate some attributes before you validate and/or save the model..

Comment: but returning false here would cancel the entire save?

Comment: Yes, there's no thing called partial save

Answer (score 0):

If you want to abort from within the setter, then raising an exception will suffice.

```
  def attribute=(attr)
    if bar
      raise "Couldn't save because blah blah"
    end
  end
```

However, as mentioned in other posts, it is likely better to do this check before save. That's what validation is for.

```
validate :my_condition

def my_condition
  if bar
    errors.add(:base, "Couldn't save because blah blah")
  end
end
```

Comment: @stackjlei: That's what I said, no?

Comment: what if i want it to silently fail?

Comment: @stackjlei: then use the other option